# Guild Wars 2 wintersday hat

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there a wintersday hat for Guild Wars 2?  I only saw one in the Black Lion trading company but was there one that was given out on December 25th?  Like on the first Guild Wars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Aside from the Winter Hat available in the gem store, there was no Wintersday hat this year. A Wizard hat was made available for free during Wintersday, but this has little to do with with Wintersday.

The wintersday items to collect this year were the Minis (also available in the gem store).

Comment: Don't forget the 15 slot bag! I think that was this year's equivalent of last year's free hat.